# C# Linq to Entities get records where date range contains dates in the current month

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have **Holiday** EF Entity:

```
public class Holiday {
    public int HolidayId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime StartDate {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime EndDate {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool IsActive {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I need to get all records that has at least one day within the current month.

For example:

```
StartDate = "2014-06-29"
EndDate = "2014-07-03"
```

If current month is July then I should get that record, because after that I will have to create a `List<int>` of all the days affecting current month. So in the last sample I will have to create a `List<int>` of:

1,2 and 3 of July.

For example:

```
StartDate = "2014-07-23"
    EndDate = "2014-08-01"
```

I should get that record also.

I was doing:

```
var holidays = Holidays.Where(h=> h.IsActive == true && h.StartDate < currentDate && h.EndDate > currentDate).ToList();
```

But, the query is not doing what I need.

Any clue?

What about this:

```
.Where(h => h.IsActive == true && (h.StartDate.Month == currentDate.Month || h.EndDate.Month == currentDate.Month)).ToList();
```

**UPDATED:**

This won't work when I have a date range where it's month is not equal to currentDate.Month. Like:

```
StartDate = "2014-06-29"
EndDate = "2014-08-03"
```

Comment: What is `currentDate`?

Comment: currentDate is today.

Comment: Your second example would work just fine, but I'm assuming that you probably want to check the `Year` too.

Comment: I tried my second example but it didnt work when I have for example StartDate= "2014-06-23" and EndDate="2014-08-01" because no one of those dates the month == currentDate.Month.

Comment: your first example should have worked...

Comment: `var holidays = Holidays.Where(h=> h.IsActive == true 
    
    && currentDate >= h.StartDate && currentDate.AddDays(-1) <= h.EndDate).ToList();`

Comment: also this would do....var result = Holidays.FindAll(h => h.StartDate < dt && h.EndDate > dt);...where dt is the currentdate.

Comment: No, because what happens if StartDate is one day after today, stills in the currentMonth but currentDate >= h.StartDate is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked is:

Maybe is not the cleanest.

```
var holidays = Uow.HolidayRepository.GetAllReadOnly().Where(h => h.IsActive == true && (h.StartDate.Month == currentDate.Month || h.EndDate.Month == currentDate.Month) || (currentDate.Month > h.StartDate.Month && currentDate.Month < h.EndDate.Month)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither test is sufficient: if the current date is today in then the first test will miss any date ranges that don't include the current date so if today is the first of the month any date range starting on the second although valid won't be caught. In addition single day ranges - unless you are including times won't be caught because the start and end dates could be equal to the current date but can never be greater than and less than - depends how you spec your date range.

The second test fails firstly because every year has months 1- 12 so not only will you be picking records for this year but for all years and secondly you miss any periods that start and end outside of the month.

Creating a list of days to compare doesn't sound efficient minimum number of runs 28 max 31.

So you need to test for ranges that either start in the current month or end in the current month as per Daniels code but in addition you need to test where the start date is before the current month and the end date is after the current month I think that should cover all cases?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do,please try it out:

```
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
var result = Holidays.AsEnumerable().Where(h => Enumerable.Range(h.StartDate.Month, (h.EndDate.Month - h.StartDate.Month) + 1).Contains(month));
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] Range(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @VAAA place .ToList() after Holidays.

Comment: I think that if I place .ToList() I will send at that point the Query to the Database. So I will brind all records.

Comment: @VAAA yes it will,so instead place .AsEnumerable()